# Java Source code is not running in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a Project in Bus Ticker Reservation. and I have also Source code but when run into eclipse got an error "Selection does not contain a main file" please help me I am new in Programming

screenshot attached

[Problem Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ws4i6.png)

Comment: Open a file which contains a `public static void main(String[])` Method and then click besides the green run button on the top, and open the drop down menu. From there move to "Run as.." and then Java

Comment: there is no such file which contains public static void main(String[]) this method

Comment: Well than you can't run it, because without a starting point it cannot start... you can create the method in any class of your choice and use the other classes inside it

Comment: You should probably learn how to run "Hello World" before moving to methods and classes

Comment: this is source code I just want to run after that i can learn everything

Comment: To be fair, he can't run "Hello World" without a main method...

Answer (score 1):

The class to be executed needs a method with the following signature: `public static void main(String[] args)`.

Comment: I have no idea please send me screenshot

Comment: @MunawarGujjar why you need screenshot?

Comment: also final, strictfp or varargs parameter types will work as well, i.e. 'public final strictfp static void main(String... args)' is valid

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a main method. When you execute a class, the runtime system starts by calling the class's main() method, so without it your class will not get executed.

So you need to add the following code to the class you are trying to run:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
     ClassName c = new ClassName();
}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 ClassName cannot be resolved to a type
 ClassName cannot be resolved to a type

 at Main.main(Main.java:6)

Comment: after adding code got this error

Comment: I used `ClassName` as an example, because i don't know what your classes are called.

Comment: can i send you source code

Comment: Add your code by editing the question

Comment: which code I send you

Comment: @MunawarGujjar of the class you are trying to run.

Comment: public class MainMenuScreen {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  MainMenuScreen c = new MainMenuScreen();
 }
 

}

Comment: this is the right way to access MainMenuScreen Class

Comment: Yes that should work.